# Problem in "between two set" hackerrank problem

Tags: java, algorithm

Problem:You will be given two arrays of integers and asked to determine all integers that satisfy the following two conditions:

The elements of the first array are all factors of the integer being considered
The integer being considered is a factor of all elements of the second array
These numbers are referred to as being between the two arrays. You must determine how many such numbers exist.

for example  :Sample Input

```
2 3
2 4
16 32 96
```

Sample Output

```
3
```

My code:

```
public static int getTotalX(int n, int m, List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    int total=0,x=0,y=0;
    for(int i=a.get(n-1);i<=b.get(0);i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {   
            //to check if the elements in list 'a' can divide the integer.
            if(i%a.get(j)==0)
            {
            y++;
            }
        }
        //if every element in list a can divide the integer go forward
        if(y==n)
            {   
                for(int k=0;k<m;k++)
                {
                    //to check if the elements of list 'b' is divisible by integer
                    if(b.get(k)%i==0)
                    {
                    x++;
                    }
                }  
                y=0;
               //if every element of 'b' is divisible by integer, count how many                        such integers are there
                if(x==m)
                {    
                    total++;
                    x=0;      
                }
            }
    }
    return total;

}
```

My code is not giving proper solution and I cant understand why.

Comment: Explain your input what does each line mean?

Comment: When you say your code isn't giving the proper solution, could you tell us what solution it *is* giving?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear, can you explain your inputs and why you got that output

Comment: Yeah! I'm sorry for being unclear. My output is coming 1 rather than 3 for the example mentioned.

Comment: It seems that your input arrays are sorted in ascending order, so I dont get your first `for` loop: shouldn't it be ``for (int i=a.get(0);i<=b.get(n-1);i++) {` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static int getTotalX(int n, int m, List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    int total = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
    for (int i = a.get(n - 1); i <= b.get(0); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i % a.get(j) == 0) {
                y++;
            }
        }
        if (y == n) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                if (b.get(k) % i == 0) {
                    x++;
                }
            }
            if (x == m) {
                total++;
            }
        }
        // changes here
        y = 0;
        x = 0;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Great progress. You were very close. Algorithm is on point and efficient.

Only one mistake: you were resetting the variables `x` and `y` inside the `if` conditions.

What if the condition is not true? Then the variables are never reset and all the future computations are done on those wrong values in `x` and `y`.

---

Like Java8? Here is a one-liner:

```
return (int) IntStream.rangeClosed(a.get(n - 1), b.get(0))
        .filter(i -> a.stream().filter(value -> i % value == 0).count() == a.size())
        .filter(i -> b.stream().filter(value -> value % i == 0).count() == b.size())
        .count();
```

Comment: You Helped! thanks for appreciation, I'm just a beginner in coding.

Comment: Well for me that is some different level but I think I can see the solution in there too, I just don't know about streams.

Comment: you can make small change to win some performance: ...filter(value -> i % value != 0).count() == 0 ... unstead of calling size() on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

My solution in Python

```
def getTotal(a,b):
  consider_ineger=[]
  for i in range(a[len(a)-1],b[0]+1):
    is_factor=False

    for n in a:
        if i%n==0:
            is_factor=True
        else:
            is_factor=False
            break
    if is_factor:
        consider_ineger.append(i)

 print(consider_ineger)
 final=[]

 for i in consider_ineger:
    is_factor=False
    for n in b:
        if n%i==0:
            is_factor=True
        else:
            is_factor=False
            break
    if is_factor:
        final.append(i)
return len(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTotalX(a, b) {
// Write your code here
var factors=[]
var smallest=b[0];
var isFactor = true;
var count = 0;
for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++){
    if (b[i]<smallest){
        smallest=b[i];
    }
}
for (var j=1; j<=smallest; j++){
    isFactor = true;
    for (var k=0; k<b.length; k++){
        if (b[k]%j!=0){
            isFactor = false;
            break;
        }
        
    }
    if(isFactor){
        factors.push(j);
        }
    
}
for (var x=0; x<factors.length; x++){
    isFactor = true;
    for (var y=0; y<a.length; y++){
       if(factors[x]%a[y]!=0){
            isFactor = false;
            break;
  
       }
    }
    if(isFactor){
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding another answer, it might help to include a brief description of how your approach works and an example of the input / output.